# Proving Bijection for a function that maps real number to set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

So I wanted to prove the following theorem.
[image]

This is the definition of a bijective function.

[image]

But unlike algebraic equation I can't reverse them to the input. Let's say function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ where $f$ is defined as $x^2$. I can just say if $x^3=y^3\implies x=y$ using algebraic manipulation but when the function maps to set I don't know how to do it. I spend my whole day wondering how to extract the decimals from set and turn it into the variable that is element of $E$ but I don't think there is set operation to do that. As a beginner I don't have much experience in analysis and set theory I hope someone enlighten me.

Comment: Be carefully, $x^2 = y^2 \Longrightarrow x= \pm y$.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I didn't say a function is algebraic operation I am just saying how do I prove bijective by using that definition.

Comment: To see that is surjective: Consider a set $A$ in the parts of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $A = \{n_1, n_2, \ldots \}$. Then we can build explicitly a point in $E$ in the following way:

Let $x=0d_{-1}d_{-2}\ldots$ such thath $d_{-j}=2$ iff $j \in A$ and $d_{-j}=1$ in another case.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari I am talking about injective.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I have thought of that before but I don't know why that would be legal move. Can you justify it?

Comment: For injective: Let $x,x' \in E$ such thath $f(x)=f(x')$, then $x$ and $x'$ have decimals expresión having de digit $2$ in the same place (because $f(x)=f(x')$. On the others decimals places, the only possibility is to have a $1$ because of the definition of $E$. So $x$ has digits $1$ where $x'$ has, and the samen with digits $2$, i.e. $x=x'$.

Comment: Right, so you get that. Good. I’ll delete my comments cause I thought you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a function is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: there is bijection between the set of all binary sequences and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Can you find a bijection between the set of all binary sequences and the set of all decimals with $1,2$?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143277/discussion-on-answer-by-shinrin-yoku-proving-bijection-for-a-function-that-maps); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.